# catkin_make error in indigo

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

i've just started using ROS. i am trying to build a package and i keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/order_paths.py", line 37, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/order_paths.py", line 32, in main
with open(args.outfile, 'w') as fh:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/build/ati_nano17_ros/catkin_generated    /ordered_paths.cmake'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):

execute_process(/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
"/usr/bin/python" "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/order_paths.py"
"/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/build/ati_nano17_ros/catkin_generated/ordered_paths.cmake"
"--paths-to-order" "/opt/ros/indigo/include" "/usr/include"
"/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/devel/include" "--prefixes"
"/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/devel" "/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/src"
"/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/devel" "/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/src"
"/home/ssc044/moveit_ws/devel" "/home/ssc044/moveit_ws/src"
"/opt/ros/indigo") returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/list_insert_in_workspace_order.cmake:29 (safe_execute_process)
/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:99 (list_insert_in_workspace_order)
ati_nano17_ros/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ssc044/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I've tried different solutions from the internet but nothing worked.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240413/catkin_make-error-in-indigo/) by [Sed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26422/sed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like a permission error in the build folder, check to make sure you have the right permissions in that folder.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26422/sed/) on 2016-07-29**:
Thank you for you response, i accessed the folder using a password, but now i have another error:

Linking CXX shared library /home/ssc044/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsr_ronex_transmissions.so
[ 35%] Built target sr_ronex_transmissions
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

**Comment by [Sed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26422/sed/) on 2016-07-29**:
i read somewhere that emptying the build folder then cmake again would do the trick. is it the right path to follow?

Thank you again